# PHP Variable loses XML

Tags: php

I have the following XML in a variable:

```
$xml = 'XML=<CktRequest><Agent Name="Computicket" Group="mobile"></Agent><Operation Type="New Session" NumNewReleases="3" NumPromotions="6"/></CktRequest>';
var_dump("xml:".$xml);
```

The var_dump only show:

```
'XML='
```

So it loses everything after that... Why?

Comment: Do what answers suggested or simply click `ctrl+u` in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is interpreting the tags as... well tags. View the source to see the contents of `$xml` or escape it first:

```
var_dump("xml:" . htmlentities($xml));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are propably having the full content shown, but viewing it through the browser it will try parsing it as HTML.

Try viewing the source code of you page. I'll bet you it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Better let the browser display the content as text and put on the beginning of your code (after "< ?php"):

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

This also helps with line-breaks ;-)